# How to use regex to find a string that is combination of numbers and letters in java?

Tags: java, regex

Given a string that looks like this "ABC789 Nusc 2888". How do I find strings like "ABC789" which is a combination of capitalized letters followed by a three digit number? Here is what I have tried

```
"[A-Z]*[0-9]{3}"
```

This helps me find "ABC789" but it also matches with " 288". What should I do to only match with "ABC789" not " 288"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want *at least one* letter then you can change `*` to `+`.

```
"[A-Z]+[0-9]{3}"
```

If you want exactly three letters, then you can repeat the `{3}` syntax.

```
"[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{3}"
```

If you have a range, you can use `{1,9}`.

```
"[A-Z]{1,9}[0-9]{3}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

When re-using it:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{3}\d{3}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ABC789 Nusc 2888");
if(m.matches()){
   printf("It matches");
}
```

When using once:

```
if(Pattern.matches("[A-Z]{3}\d{3}", "Not important XYZ123 2888"))
   printf("It matches");
}
```

[Class Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)